# Como eu a desabilito a promoção dinâmica de tipos em Groovy?

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo, groovy

Estou convertendo um aplicativo antigo de Java para Groovy. A conversão da sintaxe é tranquila. 
O problema é tipificação dinâmica do Groovy.

Vou dar um exemplo, declaro um método `foo` e sua sobrecarga:

```
int foo(String arg) {
    return 1;
}

int foo(Object arg) {
    return 2;
}
```

Então aplico o método `foo` sobre um instância do tipo `Object` que referência um tipo `String`:

```
Object obj = "PT Stack Overflow";
int resultado = foo(obj);
```

Aplicando o método em Java `System.out.println()` ou o método em Groovy `println()` obtenho resultados diferentes para cada linguagem:

**Em Java:**

```
System.out.println("Em Java o resultado é " + resultado );
> Em Java o resultado é 2
```

**Em Groovy:**

```
println("Em Groovy o resultado é " + resultado );
> Em Groovy o resultado é 1
```

Isso ocorre porque o sistema de despacho de métodos sobrecarregados do Java e do Groovy são distintos. O java escolhe o método de acordo com a assinatura dos parâmetros e o Groovy usa um sistema de auto promoção de tipos.

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para desabilitar esse sistema de tipificação dinâmica na hora de invocar métodos pois em meu aplicativo eu tenho porções de código onde há métodos sobrecarregados que realizam a mesma tarefa, porém, baseado no **tipo** do parâmetro passado o programa abre sub-formulários distintos e a conversão em Groovy fica praticamente inútil.

Comment: Você não consegue especializar mais o seu `int foo(Object arg)`, com uma interface, por exemplo?

Comment: Como que o uso de uma interface modificaria a verificação dinâmica de tipos? Pelo que eu sei uma interface apenas estipula um conjunto mínimo de métodos a ser implementados por uma  classe.

Comment: Quem negativou poderia comentar e ajudar a melhorar minha pergunta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groovy é uma linguagem dinâmica e por padrão usa um mecanismo dinâmico de despachos para executar chamadas de métodos e acessos a propriedades.

Esse sistema de despachos dinâmicos provém grande flexibilidade e poder a linguagem. Por exemplo, é possível adicionar dinamicamente métodos a classes em tempo de execução assim como é possível substituir métodos em tempo de execução. Características como essa são importantes e provém muito poder a linguagem.

De qualquer forma há momentos que se deseja desabilitar esse despacho dinâmico em favor de um mecanismo mais estático. Para isso Groovy provém um meio de informar o compilador de que uma classe em particular ou um método específico deve ser compilado estaticamente. Esse meio é marcar a classe, ou método, com o comentário [groovy.transform.CompileStatic](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html).

`groovy.transform.CompileStatic` permite ao compilador Groovy usar checagem de tipos ao estilo Java assim realizando uma compilação estática sobrepondo o protocolo Groovy para meta objetos.

Quando uma classe é marcada com `groovy.transform.CompileStatic` todos os métodos, propriedades, classes aninhadas e etc. da classe marcada herdarão essa verificação de tipos. Quando um método é marcado a compilação estática só se aplica aos seus itens(closures e classes anônimas aninhadas).

Então para fazer um método Groovy se comportar tal qual um método Java basta marcá-lo com `groovy.transform.CompileStatic` como no exemplo:

```
class Bars{

  // A anotação seguinte só se aplica em Groovy
  @groovy.transform.CompileStatic
  int foo(String arg) {
      return 1;
  }

  // A anotação seguinte só se aplica em Groovy
  @groovy.transform.CompileStatic
  int foo(Object arg) {
      return 2;
  }
}

Bars B1 = new Bars();
Object obj = "PT Stack Overflow";
int resultado = B1.foo(obj);

System.out.println("Em Java o resultado é " + resultado );
> Em Java o resultado é 2

println("Em Groovy agora o resultado é " + resultado );
> Em Groovy agora o resultado é 2
```